# i++ = ++i iS THIS TRUE OR FALSE ? explain?

Tags: c

iS THIS TRUE OR FALSE  ?  explain?

i++ = ++i

Comment: What does '=' mean here?

Comment: Compiler error because `i++` is an rvalue which cannot be assigned.

Comment: It's a syntax error - i++ is not an lvalue...

Comment: Did you mean ==? Otherwise as KennyTM said, that line gives a compiler error.

Comment: if it were (i++)+(++i) the result is undefined because there is no sequence point between the two expression parts.

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't. Either true OR false.

The problem is that C/C++ don't define when ++  happens *within* this expression.

So you have several possibilities:

1. Add 1 to `i` for the `++i` then store  that back in `i`, then add `again for the`i++`.
2. add 1 to `i` for the `i++` and save thje result for later; add 1 to `i` for the `++i` assign it to `i` and then put the saved value of `i++` into `i`.
3. Add 1 to `i` for the `i++` and then assign the result of `++i` on top of it.

It gets even better when you consider, say, `i = ++i++;`

(See the link in the comments.  The technical issue with whether there is a "sequence point" there, at which point all side effects should be resolved.  In this assignment, there's not one.)

Comment: C and C++ absolutely define what happens when ++ occurs within an expression. You can read the standard, or here's a relevant wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: Yes, dear, and if you look carefully at your reference, you'll see that assignment in this context is *not* a sequence point.

Comment: If it's undefined behaviour the list of possibilities is endless and *not* restricted to the list of "sensible" options. (http://c-faq.com/expr/evalorder4.html)

Comment: `++i++` ? Now there's something I've never tried!

Comment: @awoodland fair enough; I should have said "some of the possibilities are" instead of implying these were the only ones.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what it is you're actually getting at:

If you meant does the following expression evaluate to true:

```
i++ == ++i
```

then it's undefined behaviour because i is modified twice between sequence points.

If you meant:
do `i++;` and `++i;` do the same thing then the answer is sort of -- they both increment i. Where they differ however is if they are part of a larger statement, do they use the value before or after the increment.

In practice this means that i++ might possibly involve making a copy internally, in order to store the value before the increment, whilst ++i doesn't need to make such a copy.

If you were asking about i++ = ++i; as a statement on its own then it's not a valid statement for a more fundamental problem: the i++ cannot be the lefthand side of an assignment because of the "temporary" nature of its value.

See [this link](http://c-faq.com/expr/ieqiplusplus.html) and [this one](http://c-faq.com/expr/prevspost.html) for more discussion etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you don't know the difference between pre-increment and post-increment and you just formulated the question unintelligible:

```
i = 7;
printf("%d\n", i); // precondition: result 7
printf("%d\n", ++i); // PRE-INCREMENT: result 8 !!!
printf("%d\n", i); // postcondition: result 8

i = 7;
printf("%d\n", i); // precondition: result 7
printf("%d\n", i++); // POST-INCREMENT: result 7 !!!
printf("%d\n", i); // postcondition: result 8
```